# how to store input in local storage

Tags: javascript

Please help me to store the input in the local storage.

```js
var ul = document.getElementById('list');
var li;

var addButton = document.getElementById('add');
addButton.addEventListener('click', addItem);

var removeButton = document.getElementById('remove');
removeButton.addEventListener('click', removeItem)





function addItem() {
  //console.log("Add button clicked");
  var input = document.getElementById('input');
  var item = input.value;
  ul = document.getElementById('list');
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(item)
  localStorage.setItem('addItem', '');
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('addItem'));

  if (item === '') {
    return false;
    //add a p tag and assign a value of "enter yor todo"

  } else {
    //create li
    li = document.createElement('li');
    //create checkbox
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input')
    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    checkbox.setAttribute('id', 'check');
    //create label
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.setAttribute('for', 'item') //optional
    //add these elements on web page
    ul.appendChild(label);
    li.appendChild(checkbox);
    label.appendChild(textnode);
    li.appendChild(label);
    ul.insertBefore(li, ul.childNodes[0]);
    setTimeout(() => {
      li.className = 'visual';
    }, 2);
    input.value = '';
  }
}

function removeItem() {
  li = ul.children
  for (let index = 0; index < li.length; index++) {
    while (li[index] && li[index].children[0].checked) {
      ul.removeChild(li[index])
    }


  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Simple todo Apllication</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="controls">
      <h1>My Awesome TODO</h1>
      <input type="text" id="input"><br>
      <button type="button" id="add">ADD TODO</button>
      <button type="button" id="remove">Remove TODO</button>

    </div>
    <ul id="list">
      <li class="mycheck">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check"><label>Go to Gym</label>
      </li>
      <li class="mycheck">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check" checked><label>Record youtube video</label>
      </li>
      <li class="mycheck">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check" checked><label>Record youtube video</label>
      </li>
      <li class="mycheck">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check" checked><label>Record youtube video</label>
      </li>
      <li class="mycheck">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check" checked><label>Record youtube video</label>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <script src="todo.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

---

Comment: Please explain your specific use case. You included the code which is a good thing as we can check it to what is going wrong but you need to explain what is the expected behaviour.

Comment: What kind of data do you want to store in local storage? You need to write more in detail about what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Answer (score 0):

To store data in local storage, you can use the `localStorage.setItem` method. It takes 2 parameters. The first one is the `keyName`, i.e, the name with which data will be stored. The second one is `keyValue` which is the value that is stored in storage.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem).

The following code stores a sample TODO in the local storage.

```
localStorage.setItem("sampleTodo", JSON.stringify({"title": "sample", "description": "It is a sample Todo", "completed": false}));
```

Note that to store a JSON object, I used JSON.stringify.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this

```
localStorage.keyName = 'value';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use local storage like this:

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
// Retrieve
value = localStorage.getItem("key");
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_webstorage.asp